# 3D cube transition in IOS swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

How to do 3D cube animation in swift iOS like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxgrid6QDhi-VFMyaW1VcHlnWFE/view?usp=sharing)

I tried

```
let container = UIView()
let redSquare = UIView()
let blueSquare = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   // set container frame and add to the screen
   self.container.frame = CGRect(x: 60, y: 60, width: 200, height: 200)
   self.view.addSubview(container)

   // set red square frame up
   // we want the blue square to have the same position as redSquare 
   // so lets just reuse blueSquare.frame
   self.redSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
   self.blueSquare.frame = redSquare.frame

   // set background colors
   self.redSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
   self.blueSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

   // for now just add the redSquare
   // we'll add blueSquare as part of the transition animation 
   self.container.addSubview(self.redSquare)   
}

@IBAction func animateButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    // create a 'tuple' (a pair or more of objects assigned to a single variable)
    let views = (frontView: self.redSquare, backView: self.blueSquare)

    // set a transition style
    let transitionOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft

    UIView.transitionWithView(self.container, duration: 1.0, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
        // remove the front object...
        views.frontView.removeFromSuperview()

        // ... and add the other object
        self.container.addSubview(views.backView)

    }, completion: { finished in
        // any code entered here will be applied
        // .once the animation has completed
    })
}
```

Also found [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/cubepageview), but it is not same which I need. There are a lot of `UIViewController` 3D animations which do not fulfill my requirement, what I need is cube animation transition.

Comment: It is not necessary that you get same thing to your requirement.You just need to understande it and do modification as per necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its too late to answer but it might help someone who is looking out for a solution. Try using STCubeTransition https://github.com/Sa74/STCubeTransition. 
It allows you to translate 2 different views with cube animation.